# Faster methods for performing repeated list manipulations?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming, parallelization, compile

I've done my best to pore over the other posts on this site, and to the best of my ability I can't seem to find a good solution to my problem, so I apologize in advance if elements of my question are covered elsewhere. Basically I'm asking if there is a faster way to do what I'm trying to do. I feel like my current implementation is a bit clumsy and would like to know how it can be improved. Here's my situation:

I'm working on a population genetics simulation. You enter in some initial data, click to run the simulation, then it spits some graphs and stats back at you. The simulation tracks a population of 'creatures' over a specified number of years. Currently the simulation operates on two large lists that have roughly the same format:

```
{
  {birthYear, deathYear, geneticInfo...},
  {birthYear, deathYear, geneticInfo...},
  ...
}
```

`birthYear` is always an integer, but can be negative. `deathYear` is always a positive integer OR `Null` if the creature is alive. `geneticInfo` is a placeholder I'm using here to represent series of values (currently True|False, but I've considered making them integers) that describe different genes the creatures have. Notably, `geneticInfo` is itself not a list, just a stand in for the arbitrary number of values I may use there so `Dimensions[list]` is `{n, (2 + # of genes)}`.

The `bookOfLiving` list holds only those creatures who were alive at the beginning of the year. The `bookOfDead` list is a running tally of all creatures that have died during the course of the simulation. In practice I've found this to be faster than keeping them all in the same list, since as the years go by both lists can get quite large and therefore slow to manipulate. Of course, I'm open to changing that if something else will work better. Here is an abbreviated version of the code for the simulation:

```
While[yrsDone < yrsMax,
  yrsDone++;

  (* First determine which living creatures died this year *)
  (* The result of liveOrDie[] returns the original list of a creatures properties, *)
  (* but will replace the deathYear with an integer if they have died before breeding*)
  bookOfLiving = Map[liveOrDie[#, yrsDone, simParameters] &, bookOfLiving];

  (* Now select those whose deathYear is an integer and add them to bookOfDead *)
  bookOfDead = Join[bookOfDead, Select[bookOfLiving, IntegerQ[#[[2]]] &]];

  (* Now rewrite bookOfLiving using only those whose deathYear is not an integer *)
  bookOfLiving= Select[bookOfLiving, (!IntegerQ[#[[2]]]) &];

  (* Now determine breeding population, number of new births, and rewrite bookOfLiving, if needed *)
  bookOfLiving = With[
    {breedPop = Select[bookOfLiving, ((breedRange[[1]] <= ageNow[yrsDone, #[[1]]] <= 
      breedRange[[2]]) && (#[[2]] === Null)) &]},

      If[Length[breedPop] >= 1,
        Join[bookOfLiving, breed[breedPop, yrsDone, simParameters]], bookOfLiving]
];
```

A few notes about some other functions and variables that may help:

`simParameters`, similar to `geneticInfo`, is a placeholder for the other information that I feed into some functions and not a list (though it may contain some [typically very short] lists).

`liveOrDie[]` calls several functions to determine, given a creatures attributes and the simulation's parameters, if a creature has died that year and returns the creature's original information, but with an integer deathYear if the creature died. Because it may have to return `Null` for the death year it is currently not compiled, but the function it calls to determine the probability of death is compiled. This is probably the biggest area where slowdowns occur because I couldn't come up with a batter strategy for indicating that a death occurred without rewriting individual values in the `bookOfLiving`.

`ageNow[]` calculates a creatures' current age based on its birth year and the current year. It is compiled, but I've considered using memoization instead. For a sufficiently large population, I figure the time savings may be non-negligible (there may be thousands alive at any one time). I prefer to use the birth and death year so that when the simulation is over I can calculate what the population looked like at any given time point instead having to calculate statistics each year and save them in another form. I'm open to change on this strategy if there is a good argument for it.

`breedRange` is a pair of values defining the minimum and maximum ages at which creatures may breed. It is set before the simulation is run, so it does not change during execution. The two values are always integers greater than or equal to 0.

For the moment my biggest bottleneck is coming from the list reassignments and repeated selections, but I can't think of a good way to simplify or enhance the efficiency of these steps. I have tried to keep as many of the functions as possible compiled to save time, but this is difficult given some of the restrictions on arguments to compiled functions. Would it be worth looking into any of the new `FunctionCompile` features as compared to `Compile`? For what it's worth I've double checked that none of my compiled functions bail out of compiled execution for some reason, so that should not be a source of any slowdown. Another awkward note is that the simulation actually takes about 50% longer to run when I used `ParallelMap` instead of `Map` for determining which creatures were dead each iteration even though I launched the kernels ahead of time. Though, it is harder to compare because, as written, it appears that the kernels don't use the same RNG, because my results will differ with each run even when I set a seed in advance. Any help or advice people can provide would be greatly appreciated! I'll provide additional details if necessary, but I tried to simplify the code I provided as much as possible to make it understandable.

Comment: Gosh, the effort in the post is appreciated but it truly is hard to comment without a _working_ example. Do you have a github repo or anything?

Comment: @user6014 thanks for the kind words. Sadly, I do not have a repo (this is just a project for my own amusement, so a single notebook works for me).

Comment: If you want to upload a notebook/example dataset which demonstrates the speed issues I'd take a look (no promises it helps, but I would look :) )

Comment: "I've done my best to **pour** over the other posts on this site..." - that explains the wet feeling.

Comment: @ciao Haha, this is literally the first time I've ever had to spell that instead of speak it! You learn something every day.

Comment: One immediate improvement I can see, is to use `GroupBy[...,  IntegerQ[#[[2]]] &]` instead of using `Select` twice. That way you only have to run through the list once instead of twice. It's probably not a big deal, though. Another improvement would be to make sure your `bookOfLiving` is a matrix of just numbers. If you mix `Null` and `True` and `False` in like you do now, you won't be able to use compilation effectively. Compilation works best with just numbers. Without knowing what `breed` and `liveOrDie` do, it's difficult to say, though.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit It's not obvious from how I described it above, but when I do utilize compiled functions, I simply don't pass the Null value, so it compiles just fine without bailing out to run in the kernel. `liveOrDie` will, during its execution, call a compiled function in this kind of way `compiledFunction[creature[[1]],creature[[3]],creature[[4]], parameters]`. The booleans seem to work fine in the compiled functions, but you're just not allowed to use a tensor of booleans, iirc.

Comment: @TexasRed Not using tensors sorta defeats the purposes of compiling, though. It's better to call a compiled function once with lots of data than to call it many, many times with tiny amounts. Vectorizing operations is one of the most important ways to improve code in Mathematica.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I may not be understanding the advice you're giving, so I'll try to describe the liveOrDie function a bit more. It has two steps, the first step calls the compiled function that, given the simulation's parameters (Ex. the creature's normal life expectancy, how genes affect that, etc.) and an individual creatures' data (Ex. Its current age and genes) will return the probability of that creature dying in a given year. Because this happens for each creature each year, would there be a big benefit to calling `compiledFunction[creature, parameters]` versus how I described it above?

Comment: @TexasRed I'm sorry, but this is not enough detail to answer your question and give good advice for how to improve the performance of your code. Only if you update the code in the question with a working minimal example would it be possible to give more advice than the (admittedly vague) suggestions I already wrote in these comments. All that remains, is to direct you to one of the many existing questions here that give general advice about using compiled functions and vectorizing computations.